# Searching for a specific string above another specific string

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to write a (fairly) simple log parser to help me with debugging an application fault.

What I am currently trying to achieve is finding each instance of "Connection timed out", then finding the string "Processing file" which comes somewhere between 10-30 lines above "Connection timed out" (not always the same number of lines between).

My code currently looks something like this:

```
!#/bin/bash
connectionTimeOutLines=`zcat filename | grep -n "Connection timed out" | cut -f1 -d:` #get the line number of all instances of connection timed out
for timeOutLine in "$connectionTimeOutLines"
do
     # get the date and time the event was logged
     logDate=`zcat filename | sed "${timeOutLine}q;d" | awk '{print $1}' | awk '{print substr($0,2)}'`
     logTime=`zcat filename | sed "${timeOutLine}q;d" | awk '{print $2}'`
     # need to get the "file processed line" here
     fileProcessed="unsure what I am doing here"
     echo "$fileProcessed timed out at $logTime on $logDate" >> /tmp/logFile.log
done
```

I have edited out part of the code for brevity as it doesn't have any bearing on the question... which is: how do I find an instance of a string that comes before another string?

I can't search based purely on "Processing file" as that string appears each time a file is processed, whereas I am looking for instances where that processing has failed (with "Connection timed out").

TBH, I'm not 100% I have explained myself correctly, so I apologise in advance - please ask for any clarification where necessary!

Comment: a small, sample set of data and required output from that data would help people test your code and perhaps improve it. (Use the `{}` format tool at the top left of the edit box on highlighted text to format as code/data/output. )  FWIW, I don't have any trouble understanding your problem statement. But learn how to apply all your text processing, i.e. `sed ... | awk ... | awk ..` into one `awk cmd`, much more efficient that way. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this problem you first have to eliminate the uncertainty contained in the input:

> ... *"Processing file" which comes somewhere between 10-30 lines above "Connection timed out" (not always the same number of lines between)*

Just remove all lines except the lines of interest (those containing "Processing file" or "Connection timed out":

```
zcat filename | grep "Processing file\|Connection timed out"
```

I am pretty sure that you would be able to fetch the required data from thus preprocessed input fully on your own. Still, a complete working solution follows:

**detect_timed_out_files**

```
#!/bin/bash

F='Processing file'
T='Connection timed out'

grep "$F\|$T"                                                                  \
| sed -e "/$F/ {s/.\+Processing file \(.\+\)/\1/; h; d;}"                      \
      -e "/$T/ {H;x;s/\(\S\+\)\n\(\S\+\) \(\S\+\).*/\1 timed out at \3 on \2/}"
```

**Test input**:

```
2016-06-24 01:23:45 Processing file xxx
Humpty
Dumpty
sat
2016-06-24 01:23:46 Processing file yyy
on
a
wall
2016-06-24 01:23:51 Connection timed out
Humpty
2016-06-24 01:23:52 Processing file zzz
Dumpty
had
a
2016-06-24 01:23:53 Processing file abc
2016-06-24 01:23:59 Connection timed out
great
fall
```

**Output**:

```
$ cat input|./detect_timed_out_files 
yyy timed out at 01:23:51 on 2016-06-24
abc timed out at 01:23:59 on 2016-06-24
```